# Magento Order Amount Doubling when creating order invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, totals

i am using this code

$order->setTotalPaid($totamount)->setBaseTotalPaid($totamount); 
$order->setState('pending_validation','pending_validation', true);
$order->save();

to pay the order amount.
and also setting order status to Pending Validateion (custom order status).

After this i gose to magento backend and setting its payment validated. and order states gose to processing.
then i try to create invoice, its order amount is doubling.

[image]

Comment: Did you find why we have this behaviour and how to fix it ? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

What is the purpose behind manually setting the total paid against the order? The whole concept of an invoice is to mark a payment against the order. This is therefore automatically updating the orders total paid to include the amount the invoice is being raised for, which by default is going to be the full order amount.

You can see this behaviour in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::pay`.